# How can I get a Windows 10 build version, revision number in WINAPI?

Tags: winapi

I want to get a build version on Windows 10 using WINAPI.
Current Window Version: 10.0.19042.685

I tried to get it using WMI queries.

```
select Version, BuildNumber from Win32_OperatingSystem.
-> Version: 10.0.19042, BuildNumber: 19042
```

I tried to get it by calling RtlGetVersion().

```
HMODULE hMod = ::GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
if (hMod) {
    typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* RtlGetVersionPtr)(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW);
    RtlGetVersionPtr fxPtr = (RtlGetVersionPtr)::GetProcAddress(hMod, "RtlGetVersion");
    if (fxPtr != nullptr) {
        RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW rovi = { 0 };
        rovi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(rovi);
        if (0 == fxPtr(&rovi)) {
            printf("dwMajorVersion: %lu\n", rovi.dwMajorVersion);
            printf("dwMinorVersion: %lu\n", rovi.dwMinorVersion);
            printf("dwBuildNumber: %lu\n", rovi.dwBuildNumber);
        }
    }
}

dwMajorVersion: 10
dwMinorVersion: 0
dwBuildNumber: 19042
```

I could not obtain the revision number using WMI query and RtlGetVerion() API.

I want to get '685' from '10.0.19042.685'.

How can I get a Windows build version, revision number using WINAPI?

Comment: Have you checked `GetProductInfo`? This may be the `dwSpMinorVersion` field that it returns. I don't have convenient access to a machine to test.

Comment: 19042 is the proper build number. 685 is the "Update Build Revision" which as far as I know can only be read from the registry value `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR`.

Comment: Registry values `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR` can be easily changed. I found that the file version "ntoskrnl.exe" is the kernel version. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @snh Registry may not be the most reliable, indeed, but other info like the user-friendly version can AFAIK only be found there e.g. `ReleaseID` = `2004` under the same key.

Comment: Is there ever a situation where the revision number in the product version of ntoskrnl.exe does not match the UBR registry value (assuming that nothing has tampered with UBR)?